# VS2010 only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I've recently been told that Windows Visual Studio is one of the best IDEs for C++ development, so I decided to get it, but it's my first time using it and I'm already getting a weird error. The following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
    string name = "Player";
};

int main() {
    cout << "Works";
    return 0;
}
```

returns error C2864: 'Player::name' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class. What is wrong? This code compiled in Codeblocks IDE. Please explain to me what is wrong I don't understand.

Comment: @RobertoWilko What is the name of this feature on that list? I don't see anything that says if this is or isn't supported in VS2010.

Comment: @DavidDoria - 3rd one down. [Non-static data member initializers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm) Unfortunately, it seems VS is actually somewhat slow on adopting all of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03, you cannot initialize the data member at the point of declaration. You can do it in the constructor(s).

```
class Player {
public:
    Player() : name("Player") {}
    string name;
};
```

In C++11, your code is fine, so it could be that you were compiling with C++11 support in Codeblocks.

Comment: Thanks, that is very odd, can I somehow make VS2010 compile in C++11 as well?

Comment: @ThePlan Apparently [there is some support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx). But I don't use VS, so I wouldn't know how to enable it.

Comment: Piggy Question: Does this cause memory allocation prior to instantiation? By this I mean the C++11 standard.

Comment: @RobertoWilko allocation of the data members happens whenever a `Player` object gets instantiated. It would be equivalent to using the constructor initialization list.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Player {
public:
    string name = "Player";
};
```

This syntax has been introduced in C++11. In previous versions of standard, as C++03, that is supported by MSVC, this should look like this:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player() : name("Player") {}
    string name;
};
```